# Как я могу скрыть текущий процент выполненных работ в QProgressBar?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qprogressbar

Мой `progressBar`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

`progressBar`, который я хочу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу убрать эти цифры с `progressBar`. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: посмотрите в верхний левый угол сайта, вы ничего там не заметили?)

Comment: Maybe it can help you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pyqt5-hiding-the-progress-bar/ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658613/how-to-hide-qprogressbar-digits-progress-feedback

Comment: хммммм стак оверфлоу на русском? да не... продолжаю на английском писать :(

Comment: Мне всегда было интересно, с какой целью люди продолжают задавать вопросы на своем ломаном английском, если сайт, блин, русскоязычный...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **textVisible**: bool
>
> Это свойство указывает, должен ли отображаться текущий процент выполненных работ.
>
> Это свойство может игнорироваться стилем (например, QMacStyle никогда не рисует текст).

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt5.QtCore    import QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QVBoxLayout, QProgressBar


class ProgressBar(QProgressBar):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProgressBar, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        self.setValue(0)
        
        if self.minimum() != self.maximum():
            self.timer = QTimer(self, timeout=self.onTimeout)
            self.timer.start(randint(1, 3) * 1000)

    def onTimeout(self):
        if self.value() >= 100:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.timer.deleteLater()
            del self.timer
            return
        self.setValue(self.value() + 1)


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Window, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        pb = ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100)
        layout.addWidget(pb)
        
        pb = ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100)
        pb.setStyleSheet('text-align: center;')
        layout.addWidget(pb)

#                                                      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv        # !!!        
        pb = ProgressBar(self, minimum=0, maximum=100, textVisible=False)
        layout.addWidget(pb)
                        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    w.resize(700, 200)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]